# What's the best (and most secure) way to store token values in client side?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, token

I get a token from an autorization server that should be called only if the token expires. So I have to store that token somewhere on my client side. the problem is, I don't have a database to put it into, and I don't know if using system files is a good idea. I need your help to tell me what is the best way to store this token ?

Comment: are you going to use that token for the whole application? or the token is requested based on a specific user?

Comment: Based on your question, you got the token from a authorization server like Oauth, and what are you trying to do is use the token you got from the server and use it to your app client? If my guess is right. The best way to store the token to client side by using cookies. Here is the link from Oauth that will explain to you where to store your token. https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens

Comment: the token is used for the whole application (one token will be handled each time). In fact, I can't store it in session because the token's time to live is 90days :/ and I need to keep it for all that time somewhere (regardless if I restart my app, redeliver it...) so cookies and cache aren't a good option I guess..

Comment: why it has to be done in the client side?

Comment: Tokens are stored in a browser (client side). So every time the users (using a browser) request to your application, Instead of providing the username and password, browser will use the tokens to send it to your app and your app will verify the token using a algorithm. So basically token was used every time they request to your API endpoint. Its something like, user login to your app (api/login) and then server will verify the username and password then if verified server will return the token containing (if user has access to a certain endpoints) and then your client side or the browser save

Comment: Save the token to a cookie. Why it has to be done in the client side

Answer (score 1):

You can save authentication information in the browser using cookies.
Many modern websites using cookies to store token.
If you use cookies the browser will automatically send the authentication information with every request to the API. This can be convenient so long as you know it's happening.

Comment: I see...  but how can I store the token for 90 days (I have to)? so that each time I restart my app or deliver a new version I can still use the same token..

Comment: You can set max age of cookie for 90 days.